# macOS text substitutions: How do I distinguish lowercase and uppercase characters

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, text, internationalization

When using the keyboard shortcuts functionality in macOS (i.e. substitution of a sequence of characters to another sequence of characters), I see that it's randomly detecting the uppercase vs. lowercase.

e.g. :

- if I write "\Theta" I get the uppercase Theta Θ, perfect.
- if I write "\theta" I get the lowercase theta θ, perfect.
- if I write "\Omega" I end up the the uppercase Ω, perfect.
- if I write "\omega" I end up the the uppercase Ω, not perfect, even though in System Preferences I mapped lowercase "\omega" to the lowercase omega symbol ω.

Is this normal? What can I do so that it distinguishes lowercase and uppercase characters all the time ?

(I'm currently running macOS High Sierra 10.13.5)

[image]

---

**Edit  :** Some shortcuts stop to work when I add another but others start to work again doing so. For example : "^2" was working but not "ⁿ" (i.e. "^n"). When I added τ (i.e. "\tau") the "^2" stopped working but the "ⁿ" now works back. Also, since I added "τ" the ω and Ω is now solved. How strange. There seems to be some conflicts between some shortcurts.

Comment: I can't duplicate your problem using TextEdit.  Does this happen to you in all apps? You might try running your OS in English instead of French.  It is hard to see how such a problem could depend on the OS language, but you never know...

Comment: It happens in all apps where substitution is activated (TextEdit, Safari, Mail, etc.). I did not try english. That problem is random (i.e. depends on which characters) and might be hard to reproduce. For example, σ and Σ using lowercase or uppercase doesn't have this problem. But gamma and Gamma generate Γ and Γ uppercase, which is the same problem as the one with omega and Omega.

Comment: Gamma/gamma DOES show this problem on my machine too.  But also Sigma/sigma!  How strange!